# Como fazer projeto web com wildfly 16?

Tags: mysql, java-ee, eclipse, wildfly

Não consigo visualizar um *HTML File*, do WebContent, de teste de arquivo através do link (localhost:8080/Loucademia/teste.html), dá erro(404); o que significa que não to conseguindo acessar pelo navegador. Meu servidor de aplicações é o WildFly versão 16.0.0 e já está com *datasource* para o MySQL e com *driver* para o MySQL. Aparecem alguns erros no console que não consigo resolver, referentes a JBOSS e HIBERNATE. Estou usando JPA também, e JSF.

**Criei essa classe no src:**

---

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig.Version;

@FacesConfig( version = Version.JSF_2_3)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Config {

}
```

---

**Erros no console quando reinicio o servidor:**

---

[image: Erros parte I]

[image: Erros parte 2]

[image: Erros parte 3]

Ajudem-me, galera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi!

Criei um DataSource de forma errada. Ao invés de colocar o usuário e senha da conexão do MySQL, coloquei user and pass do WildFly. Putz!